# How to efficiently compare an array of objects with another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a function where I have to return an array of elements with matching filters. Here's the function code:

```
filter_getCustomFilterItems(filterNameToSearch: string, appliedFilters: Array<any>) {
   let tempFilterArray = [];
   let masterFilterList = getMasterFilterList();
   /*
   filterNameToSearch can be a string either as `Item2` or `Item3`

   masterFilterList will be of type
   masterFilterList: Array<any> = [
   {
      Item1: 'some-item-1',
      Item2: 'some-item-2',
      Item3: 'some-item-3',
      Item4: 'some-item-5',
   },
   {
      Item1: 'some-item-10',
      Item2: 'some-item-11',
      Item3: 'some-item-12',
      Item4: 'some-item-13',
   },......
  ];  

  appliedFilters will be of type
  appliedFilters: Array<any> = [
   {
      name: 'Item1',
      filters: [
          {value: 'some-item-1', status: 'selected'},
          {value: 'some-item-10', status: 'selected'}
      ]
   },......
  ];  
 */

 for (let masterFilterItem of masterFilterList) {
   //Missing logic here
 }
}
```

I would like to filter the `masterFilterList` to return an array of items 
`filterNameToSearch = 'Item2'` under the following conditions:

1) for each array element (assume `appliedFilterItem`) in `appliedFilters`, compare `appliedFilterItem.name` with `masterFilterItem[appliedFilterItem.name]` and check if any of the filters in `appliedFilterItem` has the same value as `masterFilterItem[appliedFilterItem.name]`

2) The condition has to look like something like `masterFilterItem[appliedFilterItem[0].name] == appliedFilterItem[0].filters[0].value && appliedFilterItem[0].filters[0].status === 'selected' && masterFilterItem[appliedFilterItem[1].name] == appliedFilterItem[1].filters[0].value && appliedFilterItem[1].filters[0].status === 'selected' and so on for all appliedFilterItems`. But the number of elements in the `appliedFilters` is dynamic.

So please help me out with this issue?

Comment: Its unclear what your required output is

Comment: The output will be an array of items in `masterFilterList`, with the conditions applied. If given filterNameToSearch = "Item2", it has to return all `Item2` elements in `masterFilters` with conditions from `appliedFilters`

Answer (score 2):

```
  return masterFilterList.map(el => el[filterNameToSearch])
      .filter(value => 
         appliedFilters.some(({name, filters}) =>
            name === filterNameToSearch &&
            filters.some(filter => 
              filter.status === "selected" &&
              filter.value === value
            )
         )
      );
```